# Why do we need one jump after changing `PG` with `mov CR0, ...` when using non-completely serializing instruction?

Tags: assembly, x86, paging, virtual-memory, osdev

In the [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual Volume 3A 9.3 SERIALIZING INSTRUCTIONS](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/intel-sdm.html)

> - When an instruction is executed that **enables or disables paging** (that is, changes the PG flag in control register
>   CR0), the instruction should be **followed by a jump instruction**. The target instruction of the jump instruction is
>   fetched with the new setting of the PG flag (that is, paging is enabled or disabled), but the jump instruction
>   itself is **fetched with the previous setting**. The Pentium 4, Intel Xeon, and P6 family processors do not require
>   the jump operation following the move to register CR0 (**because** any use of the MOV instruction in a Pentium 4,
>   Intel Xeon, or P6 family processor to write to CR0 is **completely serializing**). However, to maintain backwards
>   and forward compatibility with code written to run on other IA-32 processors, it is **recommended** that the jump
>   operation be performed.

"serializing instructions" will "serialize the instruction execution stream" **before** it runs to avoid the reordering.

Q:

1. What is the purpose of the "jump instruction" after the special serializing instruction related with paging (i.e. `mov` with **one `CR0` register operand**)? Does it imply refreshing the page table or others?
2. What does "**completely** serializing" imply so that it **doesn't need** the jump following the "serializing instructions"?

**Edited**:

In the doc of March 2023 version with Order Number 325462-079US, it doesn't list `jmp` in "Non-privileged serializing instructions" and "Privileged serializing instructions" although it seems that [`jmp` is one serializing instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57115764/how-does-the-jmp-instruction-affect-the-8086s-working#comment131787255_57115933). This where my confusion is because it suddenly use the "jump" term in one item of section 9.3 without reusing it in other items of that section.

Then after rereading the doc following the hints of the answers. In 10.9.2 Switching Back to Real-Address Mode, it says:

> 7. Execute a far JMP instruction to jump to a real-address mode program. This operation **flushes the instruction
>    queue** and loads the appropriate base-address value in the CS register.

And it has one example asm code in 10.10.2 STARTUP.ASM Listing (Here I includes the line number) showing "flush" of "the instruction
queue":

```
179 ; clear prefetch queue
180 JMP CLEAR_LABEL
```

One more small question after reading the answers:

1. Is `jmp` one serializing instruction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Completely serializing" implies that code prefetch buffers / pipeline stages are discarded, so code-fetch of those instruction bytes is re-done with the new interpretation of CS:EIP (as a virtual address to be translated by the page tables), rather than executing already-fetched instructions using the old linear=physical interpretation.  (Or if disabling paging, then the reverse, old being linear=virtual.)

Without a jump, on old CPUs where `mov cr0, reg` is non-serializing, execution of later instructions *could* use the results of code fetches that used the old interpretation of CS:EIP.

(A serializing instruction like `cpuid` or [the new `serialize`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/serialize) is actually needed even on new CPUs for a case like `if (new_code_written_by_another_core) jmp new_code` - [release/acquire semantics](https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/) happen for free (no asm fence instructions) on x86 due its strongly-ordered memory model, but code-fetch is separate from data loads.  A thread has to run as-if loads ran in program order, but that only applies to data loads not code-fetch, so old machine code could have already been fetched before seeing the flag that says new machine code has been stored.  If machine code for later instructions might be stale, run a serializing instruction to stop it from being fetched until after all the loads/stores before the serializing instruction.  Perhaps this helps understand the point of being fully serializing.)

Out-of-order exec CPUs (P6 being Intel's first) don't rename CR0, so writing CR0 had to be special anyway.  As well as `PG`, it [contains other critical bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_register#Control_registers_in_Intel_x86_series) like `PE` (protected-mode enable, which changes the semantics of `mov Sreg, r/m16`).
Making `mov cr0, src` also flush the front-end makes the old `mov`/`jmp` sequence still guarantee everything that was previously guaranteed for enabling/disabling paging, but puts the cost in the mov to CR0.  So `jmp` can do branch prediction and speculative execution without any checks for a recently-changed-CR0, which is desirable since `jmp` is widely used in normal code.

`jmp`/`jcc`/`loop`/`call` aren't "serializing instructions" in the x86 technical-terminology sense, but on older in-order CPUs had [semantics for self-modifying code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17395557/observing-stale-instruction-fetching-on-x86-with-self-modifying-code) based on how 8086 discarded the prefetch queue on every jump.  (Only *self*-modifying, not *cross*-modifying from another thread, though.  Modern x86 has stronger SMC detection that avoids making `jmp` special at all, because that was the highest-performance way to still satisfy the requirements in the paper manuals and be compatible with older CPUs.) See also [Is there a cheaper serializing instruction than cpuid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23280697/is-there-a-cheaper-serializing-instruction-than-cpuid/75456027#75456027) re: true serializing instructions vs. ordering other things (like `lfence` ordering execution but not code-fetch or the store buffer.)

---

Normally the code to enable or disable paging is in an identity-mapped page (virtual = physical address), so it shouldn't matter much (if at all?) whether or not you jump right away. Unless your code is near the end of that page and the next one isn't identity-mapped.  Or unless there's some interaction with other machine-state changing instructions you might run later, something other than "stale" code fetch that's relevant.  I can't think of any, but maybe I'm overlooking something.  Like perhaps setting the Accessed bit in the page-table entry for this code page right away, which wouldn't happen with non-paged accesses.  That's not important for most code, but Intel doesn't want to make any assumptions.

Also, if the page containing `mov cr0, eax` is *not* identity-mapped, you can't count on instruction fetch from the virtual page (mapped to a different physical address) happening for the address right after the `mov`.  That's one reason Intel needs to at least document the behaviour, even though I'm pretty sure most code doesn't actually *need* a `jmp` right away.

A jump right away seems like a reasonable defensive-coding practice (on CPUs before P6 / P4) that ensures you get a page-fault right away if your page tables are wrong, not confusingly at some later point once the prefetch buffer gets to instructions that were fetched from virtual CS:EIP.

Intel manuals have tended to be conservative about recommended code sequences for stuff like this.  e.g. their sequence for changing from real mode to long mode involved temporarily entering protected mode.  Current CPUs in practice work fine if you go directly from real to long mode, and the docs for the control-register bits imply it should work, but some people are reluctant to assume future CPUs will support that shorter sequence because Intel's manuals don't show an example or even mention doing it that way.  https://wiki.osdev.org/Setting_Up_Long_Mode Since most OSes only do this once performance is irrelevant, and it only takes a bit of extra startup code, like maybe a few tens of bytes of kernel size, so it's not crazy to follow the manual's example because that's pretty much guaranteed not to break in future CPUs.

In this case I suspect this was just the easiest and simplest way to communicate that if you get the page tables wrong, you'll get a page fault in fetching the jump target, not the instruction right after `mov cr0, eax`, unless you're on a newer CPU.  Because software bugs do happen, and it's hard enough to understand them, especially back in the bad old days when it was more common to test only on real hardware, not in an emulator where you could single-step and have it tell you why the system crashed even if you're in the middle of switching modes and don't have an IVT or IDT set up with any crash-reporting double-fault handler.

On paper, Intel doesn't guarantee that all later CPUs (from Intel or other vendors) will still have serializing `mov cr0, src` so they recommend doing the `jmp` here (probably just for early and consistent detection of problems with page tables.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer although this question is asked a bit long before. In summary, could I think that the `jmp` purpose is to check the page table validity, then the fault handler could **correct** it if any errors with the page table (1. "the jump instruction itself is fetched with the previous setting" is to ensure `jmp` works 2. "followed by a jump instruction" means not strict follow by "not the instruction **right** after `mov cr0, eax`")? Since "completely serializing" **ensures** that the page table works well, so we don't need `jmp` in this case, is that right?

Comment: What does "something other than "stale" code fetch that's relevant" mean? Could you say more specifically detailedly with one example of what is "something" here?

Comment: I add one more question. Could you help answering it?

Comment: @zgc: Yes, the `jmp` recommendation is to check the page-table for validity *right away*.  In theory you could write your OS to intentionally page-fault in a way the fault handler knows how to repair (paging in new code from disk or something?  Or just building the actual tree of page directories and page-table entries if your OS only updated its own bookkeeping stuff without creating HW PTEs).

Comment: @zgc: *"the jump instruction itself is fetched with the previous setting" is to ensure jmp works* - no, that's a description of the consequences of the way older CPUs work, where `mov cr0, eax` isn't serializing so later instructions (including a `jmp` if that's what's next) were probably already fetched before the change to CR0 took effect. That made the hardware simpler. If every instruction after `mov cr0, eax` was fetched using virtual addressing, `jmp` wouldn't be useful to make sure the CPU starts doing virtual code fetch.  That's how newer CPUs work, where `mov cr0, eax` is serializing.

Comment: @zgc: *What does "something other than "stale" code fetch that's relevant" mean?* - I have no idea what there might be that I'm not thinking of. I think probably nothing, but it's remotely possible that there's some other reason a `jmp` is useful.  I didn't want to make an absolute statement that Intel's manual is purely being over-cautious.  BTW, I updated my answer to explain that `jmp` isn't a serializing instruction.  Your edit got a couple things backwards from the points I was trying to make so I rephrased those, too.

Comment: To answer your 2nd new comment, I said something with ambiguity. ""the jump instruction itself is fetched with the previous setting" is to ensure jmp works" means that it is to ensure `jmp` instruction can be fetched **if it is the immediate next instruction** otherwise with the paging configuration changed maybe **the next instruction is not `jmp`**. Is it that case?

Comment: @zgc: That would be possible if the current page isn't identity-mapped, so interpreting the address as virtual results in code-fetch from a different physical page.  That would be unusual, as it would make `mov cr0, eax` act as a jump on CPUs that did serialize.  But the phrasing of "is to ensure" implies that this was the motivation for a design choice (of not making mov to CR0 serializing in 386 through P5).  That's not the case.  The design choice is to keep the HW simple by not serializing.  The consequence is unpaged fetch of later insns, which HW allows SW to work around with `jmp`.

Comment: @zgc: One possible "other factor" I later thought of: code-fetch will set the Accessed bit in the page table entry for the current page, but not if execution goes off the end of the page still based on fetches that happened before the `mov cr0, eax` took effect.  Or the `jmp` might be a far jump to a 32-bit CS, if you were originally in 16-bit protected mode, in which case instructions might decode differently.  Or if the `mov` to CR0 was also enabling protected mode in the first place then you'd need to `jmp` or `call` to set CS to load a segment descriptor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256442/discussion-between-zg-c-and-peter-cordes).

Comment: @zgc: re: `jmp` being *guaranteed* to be fetched unpaged: it's not guaranteed.  If interrupts are enabled, one could happen between `mov cr0, eax` and a later `jmp`, resulting in a jump (and probably a serializing `iret`.)  Or if other cores were writing the cache line containing the `jmp` (perhaps just false-sharing, not cross-modifying code), this core might not have gotten access to it yet to read the machine code.  Or maybe with an MTRR setting making that memory uncacheable.

Answer (score 2):

Fetching of instructions is actually reading memory and treat the data as code.

In case that you are continue fetching the instructions with PG=0, that means that the code will not go through the translation and the IP will continued to be "flat" (without translation).

After the jmp/serialized instruction, the instruction will go to a new path and use the "new" translation as the correct code to fetch from.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. With your hint, I read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57115933/21294350), it says "jumps discard the instruction prefetch queue in 8086". So here the `jmp`'s purpose is to **avoid usage of the old prefetch queue**. Since "That's not great and is an extra cost for jumps" as the reference link says, we use `jmp`. However we can also use other serialized instructions like `cpuid` although `cpuid` is heavy. Is my understanding right?

Comment: After rereading the doc, it doesn't list `jmp` in "Non-privileged serializing instructions" and "Privileged serializing instructions", but it has "The JMP or CALL instruction **immediately after** the MOV CR0 instruction changes the flow of execution and **serializes** the processor." in "10.9.1 Switching to Protected Mode". Then is `jmp` one **serializing** instruction?

Comment: yes your understanding is correct.
Jmp is not a serialized instruction by its own.
and only now I see that Peter already answered everything, so you are in a very good hand :D