# Why I cannot single stepping into aeskeygenassist instruction in self-modifying code?

Tags: linux, debugging, assembly, x86, aes

I tried implementing aes128 encryption using assembly language, my final goal is to find out the final value. when debugging (using single stepping), the debugger stops at the `0x8048074` address.

Here the code :

```
global _start
section .text

_start:

pxor    xmm2, xmm2
pxor    xmm3, xmm3
mov     bx, 0x36e5
mov     ah, 0x73

roundloop:
shr     ax, 7
div     bl
mov     byte [sdfsdf+5], ah

sdfsdf:
aeskeygenassist xmm1, xmm0, 0x45
pshufd  xmm1, xmm1, 0xff

shuffle:
shufps  xmm2, xmm0, 0x10
pxor    xmm0, xmm2
xor     byte [shuffle+3], 0x9c
js      short shuffle

pxor    xmm0, xmm1
cmp     ah, bh
jz      short lastround

aesenc  xmm3, xmm0
jmp     short roundloop

lastround:
aesenclast xmm3, xmm0
ret
```

Debugger stuck at here, I cannot `single-stepping` to `0x804807a`

```
[-------------------------------------code-------------------------------------]
   0x804806c <_start+12>:       mov    ah,0x73
   0x804806e <roundloop>:       shr    ax,0x7
   0x8048072 <roundloop+4>:     div    bl
=> 0x8048074 <roundloop+6>:     mov    BYTE PTR ds:0x804807f,ah
   0x804807a <sdfsdf>:  aeskeygenassist xmm1,xmm0,0x45
   0x8048080 <sdfsdf+6>:        pshufd xmm1,xmm1,0xff
   0x8048085 <shuffle>: shufps xmm2,xmm0,0x10
   0x8048089 <shuffle+4>:       pxor   xmm0,xmm2
```

I'm using [peda](https://github.com/longld/peda) plugin for GDB.

**EDIT :**

Sorry, I don't mention the error message, error message is `Segmentation fault` at this instruction `mov    BYTE PTR ds:0x804807f,ah`

Comment: What happens when you single step?

Comment: You might want to mention in the question that you’re using self-modifying code—it seems to be a key aspect of the problem. Include the byte encoding of the original instruction and what it is being modified to, so we don’t have to look it up.

Comment: Also, you can't `ret` from `_start` under Linux; it's not a function.  RSP points to `argc`, not a return address.  Also, use `default rel` for RIP-relative addressing of the store; it's more compact.

Comment: @prl yeah, I get `Segmentation fault` message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I assume you forgot to link with `--omagic` to make the .text section writable.**

---

**So `mov    BYTE PTR ds:0x804807f,ah` segfaults, and it's *right* before `aeskeygenassist`**.  You can't keep single-stepping after your program crashes.  (You have no handler for SIGSEGV, and the default action is to terminate your program).

When I tried this on my desktop out of curiosity, I can imagine interpreting the behaviour as single-stepping getting "stuck" before `aeskeygenassist`, if I ignore the segfault message!!! and the fact that trying again says "the program is no longer running".

From a GDB session:

```
(gdb) layout reg
(gdb) starti          # like run with an implicit breakpoint on the first instruction
(gdb) si
0x0000000000401004 in _start ()
0x0000000000401008 in _start ()     ## I kept pressing return to repeat the command
0x000000000040100c in _start ()
0x000000000040100e in roundloop ()
0x0000000000401012 in roundloop ()
0x0000000000401014 in roundloop ()    # the MOV store

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000401014 in roundloop ()    # still pointing at the MOV store
```

Notice that RIP is still pointing at the `mov`.  `0x8048074` in your 32-bit build,  `0x401014` in my 64-bit build of the same source.

---

From the `ld` manual:

> `-N`
>      `--omagic`
>          Set the text and data sections to be readable and writable.  Also, do not page-align the data segment, and disable linking against
>   shared
>              libraries.  If the output format supports Unix style magic numbers, mark the output as "OMAGIC". Note: Although a writable text
>   section is
>              allowed for PE-COFF targets, it does not conform to the format specification published by Microsoft.

Your code works fine for me if I link with:

```
  nasm -felf64 aes.asm &&
  ld --omagic aes.o -o aes
```

Alternatively, you could make an `mprotect` system call to give the page containing this code `PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC`.

**GDB's `layout reg` disassembly window even updates disassembly for `aeskeygenassist` after its immediate is modified by store.**

---

Also note that Self-Modifying Code (SMC) is *extremely* slow on modern x86.  Full [pipeline nuke after every store near instructions being executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17395557/observing-stale-instruction-fetching-on-x86-with-self-modifying-code).  You'd be much better off unrolling with an assembler macro.

**Also, you can't `ret` from `_start` under Linux; it's not a function. The stack pointer points to `argc`, not a return address.**  Make an `_exit` system call with `int 0x80` for 32-bit code.  When I say "works" I meant it reaches that `ret` and segfaults on code-fetch from address `1` after popping `argc` into RIP.

Also, use `default rel` for RIP-relative addressing of the store; it's more compact.  Or I guess you're building a 32-bit executable out of this for some reason, based on your code addresses.  I didn't notice that at first, that's why I tested as a 64-bit executable.  Fortunately you used labels correctly, and `aeskeygenassist` is the same length in both modes, so it still works.

Comment: Wow, nice answer and clean explaination :)

Comment: @nornor: if my guess (and this answer) are correct, you can accept this by clicking the checkmark under the up/down vote arrows.

Comment: sure, btw what is `default rel` ?

Comment: @nornor: https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc6.html#section-6.2.1 it makes addressing modes like `[sdfsdf+5]` use x86-64 RIP-relative addressing by default, so you don't have to write `[rel sdfsdf+5]`.

Comment: Hello @PeterCordes, do you have some references about optimization using `gcc`, it something line `gcc -O3 .....` ?

Comment: @nornor: no idea what kind of answer you're looking for.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html documents which specific GCC options `-O3` enables.  Or maybe you mean something like [gcc optimization flag -O3 makes code slower than -O2](//stackoverflow.com/q/28875325) that shows a difference between O2 and O3 other than auto-vectorization?  Or [C loop optimization help for final assignment (with compiler optimization disabled)](//stackoverflow.com/a/32001196) discusses some optimization-level effects.

Comment: this is not about this answer of my question :D, i'm just asking ... , thanks for the references. optimization like **readable assembly** generate from `-S` flag

Comment: @nornor: [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](//stackoverflow.com/q/38552116)