# on the fly instruction patching

Tags: debugging, low-level

I have create a small debugger for Linux.
I have tried to create a mechanism which encrypts binary instructions and decrypts them just before execution (I have set hardware breakpoints or step-by-step running).
It works 99 times out of 100.

I think the problem is due to L1 cache.
When I try to decrypt an instruction, this instruction is already in CPU L1 cache.
I have tried on ARM64 and x86_64. I got the same results.

My question is how debuggers like gdb or lldb can patch breakpoints instruction without L1 cache side effects ?

Thanks

Comment: My understanding is that this isn't a problem on x86: a data write automatically invalidates a cached instruction at the same address, in the unusual situation where you are both writing and executing the same memory area.  Other architectures may require you to do an explicit cache flush after modifying memory that's going to be executed.

Comment: [Observing stale instruction fetching on x86 with self-modifying code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17395557) - not possible on current microarchitectures.  It's a non-problem on x86, L1i cache is coherent and even already-fetched instruction addresses are snooped by stores.  Whatever bug you have, it's not caused by that on x86-64.  On ARM and AArch64, you do have to invalidate I cache and force write-back of data cache out to the point of unification so I-fetch will see recent stores.  (With appropriate barrier instructions to make sure those fetches don't happen until after the write-back.)

Comment: Although that's only when the code modification happens in the same thread (actually same core).  But modifying another process's memory via `ptrace` would involve an `iret` for it to get back to user-space I'm pretty sure, which is a serializing instruction.  If you were doing the modification in an interrupt-handler on the same core (in a kernel module?), this would be a non-problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The x86/x86_64 is an unusual beast, in that if you write to instruction memory, it will invalidate that line of the caches so you don't need to do anything. This is for backward compatibility to chips from the 1980's when there wasn't any caching. This means that for that processor, the L1 cache certainly isn't the problem, unless you are modifying an instruction using a different linear address as described below:

https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-3a-part-1-manual.pdf

> 11.6 SELF-MODIFYING CODE A write to a memory location in a code segment that is currently cached in the processor causes the associated cache line (or lines) to be invalidated.

The exception is if you are doing something weird with the address mapping (from the same section of the document):

> Systems software, such as a debugger, that might possibly modify an
> instruction using a different linear address than that used to fetch
> the instruction, will execute a serializing operation, such as a CPUID
> instruction, before the modified instruction is executed, which will
> automatically resynchronize the instruction cache and prefetch queue.

So on the x86_64, you could try a CPUID instruction.

Except for this case, your problem won't be the caches at all - I'd go looking elsewhere, such as looking for race conditions (you haven't said what the non-working case looks like).

For other modern processors (including ARM), you will need to invalidate the relevant part of the instruction cache yourself.

https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0344/k/Babhejba

Comment: As shown in *[Observing stale instruction fetching on x86 with self-modifying code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17395557)*, current microarchitectures (Intel since P6) make it impossible to observe stale instruction fetch even when writing via a different virtual address for the same physical page.  On paper that's not guaranteed without a serializing instruction like `cpuid` or `serialize`, but in practice you only need that for **cross**-modifying code.

Comment: e.g. after another software thread (on another core) writes  some instructions, normal acquire / release sync from seeing a `code_ready` flag isn't sufficient.  You do need a serializing instruction to make sure the front-end hasn't fetched stale data from before our data load saw the flag; LoadLoad ordering only applies to data loads.  (Modifying another process's memory via `ptrace` should involve a serializing `iret` as it returns to user-space.  Unless it's just a `sysret`?  But I think Linux specifically avoids `sysret` if `ptrace` has been used, at least if regs have been modified.)